# Identifying duplicate group in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table in SQL where one person is allocated multiple cities. I want to make the group of these cities.

```
Name    | City
Per 1   | A
Per 1   | B
Per 1   | C

Per 2   | A
Per 2   | B

Per 3   | A
Per 3   | B
Per 3   | C

Per 4   | D
Per 4   | E

Per 5   | A
Per 5   | B
```

Region wise group of these cities will look like this.

```
Region  | City
Reg 1   | A
Reg 1   | B
Reg 1   | C

Reg 2   | A
Reg 2   | B

Reg 3   | D
Reg 3   | E
```

Is it possible to do in SQL 2014?

Comment: Where does the `Region` come from? What is the logic?

Comment: what is the expected output? What you have done till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'Reg ' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(3)) [Region], [Cities] from (
    --this query perform concatenation of cities (separated by comma) Name-wise
    select distinct replace(replace((select city + ',' from @x where Name = X.Name for xml path('')), '<city>',''),'</city>','') [Cities]
    from @x [X]
) a
```

The result is:

```
Region   Cities
Reg 1    A,B,
Reg 2    A,B,C,
Reg 3    D,E,
```

I hope it's acceptable :)

Comment: Ideally you'd need to unroll the results to be able to store the many:many relationship in a normalized table.

Comment: @Deepakgupta Please accept the answer, so it won't require anymore attention from moderators.

Comment: @michal - You do not need to replace <city> and </city>. Concatenated string is comma separated without <city>,</city>.

Comment: "require anymore attention from moderators"??